# Issue while invoking chrome browser with Selenium Driver

Tags: java, selenium

When i am trying to invoke chrome browser in eclipse using selenium driver with Java , i am getting an error.

Please help me out in resolving this issue.

Below is my code -

```
package packagedefault;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChromeBrowser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://google.com");

    }

}
```

Below is the error message i am getting -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/config/RegistryBuilder
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.<init>(ApacheHttpClient.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.<init>(DriverCommandExecutor.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.java:36)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at packagedefault.ChromeBrowser.main(ChromeBrowser.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: What jars do you have in classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below code inside main() function

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--test-type");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://google.com");
```

Works properly here in my windows PC

Comment: @user8940249 did you get your answer?

Comment: @user8940249 did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Exception you mentioned

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/http/config/RegistryBuilder

Occured when `jars` files are not available.
Import only the `selenium-server-standalone- jars` and try your code .

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Path of chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("https://google.com");
```